# Error when creating stored procedure SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i'am getting error on '{' and 'END'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getLogsdata 
{
    @id int
}
AS
BEGIN

END
```

how to remove this errors

Comment: use parenthesis `()` instead of curly braces `{}`.

Comment: thanks it's working

Comment: @MohammadAltaf: Don't forget to upvote the answer if it's working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parenthesis `()` instead of curly braces `{}`, and include some code in your procedure.

```
create procedure dbo.getLogsdata (@id int) as
  begin;
    set nocount on;

    select *
    from dbo.logs
    where id = @id;
  end;
go
```